# How do I log into Stack Overflow using a different google account than signed in with in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, stack-overflow

I run two Chrome profiles on my laptop:

1. Personal - Used for all my Stack Overflow accounts
2. Work - Used for work Google account

Both are signed into their respective Google accounts.

How do I log into Stack Overflow using my personal account on my works Chrome user?

Comment: You will need to sign out of your work account, if you want to sign into your personal account. Did you consider setting up several Chrome profiles? https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a support question that is more appropriate for [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is adding your work login to your Stack Overflow account.

Here's how:

- Login to Stack Overflow from your Personal Chrome User profile.
- Logout of your **personal** Gmail.
- Add more logins from your Stack Overflow profile page

[image: Screenshot showing 'add more logins' link]

- Next, "Login with Google" and sign in with your **work** Gmail.

  - *This should work because you logged out of your personal Gmail in step 2*

[image: Screenshot showing 'Login with Google' option]

- Go to Gmail and Logout of your work profile and re-login with your personal profile.

  - *This to bring everything back to normal on your Personal Chrome User profile.*
- From your Work Chrome User profile, visit Stack Overflow and login with your work Gmail.